# Nature of relationship between a cone and a pair of planes

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, quadrics

A cone is defined as a surface generated by lines passing through a fixed point and interesecting a given conic, or touching a given surface.
A pair of non-parallel planes seems to loosely satisfy these properties. We can loosely call a pair of planes as a cone with an infinite number of vertices (any point on the line of intersection of the planes being a vertex) and the guiding curve being two non-intersecting lines meeting at infinity. The pair of planes satisfies the property of cone which says that any line joining the vertex with a point of the cone has to lie on the cone. (being a generating line)
I understand that most of my claims are hand wavy but I doubt that this is just a coincidence. So the question is mathematically speaking, what is the relationship between cones and pairs of planes?
Kindly explain in simple language. I am familiar with only undergraduate level mathematics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to think of 2 intersecting planes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a cone?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820188/how-to-think-of-2-intersecting-planes-in-mathbbr3-as-a-cone)

Comment: @brainjambrain No, it doesn't. Since first of all it deals with some projective geometry theory, which I am not familiar with. Secondly, the question defines a cone as a right circular cone, not a general cone. Also an answer to this question should explain why these particular properties are satisfied by both the surfaces. Also I am fascinated by how two infinite lines could be looked as a closed curve and consequently two parallel lines on the two planes could be considered as a very large loop or a guiding curve of a cone. I am sure all this and more can be discovered by some rigorous math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, cones enjoy **different definitions**.

1 - In **linear algebra**, a cone is a subset of a real vector space that is closed under multiplication by a positive scalar, cf. Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone

So yes, with this definition two non-parallel planes make a cone.

Apart from being one of Wikipedia's definitions for a cone (and they add "sometimes called a linear cone for distinguishing it from other sorts of cones"), this is also the definition used in conic optimization, cf. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_optimization

This closedness by positive multiplication is actually usefull in proofs related to optimization algorithms, i.e. it is a well-thought concept; although usually coupled with convexity: cones considered in optimization are convex cones.

2 - That being said, two non-parallel planes are also a cone according to the **definition you adopt**, which is also widely used, i.e. "lines passing through a fixed point and intersecting a given conic": two non-parallel planes are equal to lines passing through a fixed point and two intersecting lines, and two intersecting lines are a (degenerate) conic: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic

$\\$

**EDIT**
Following comments, here is a **construction** to relate a circular cone and two planes.
The idea is: as two intersecting lines are a degenerate conic, they can be parameterized in the same way as other conics.

We'll use as two lines in the projective plane $\mathbb P^2$ the principal axes: $x=0$ and $y=0$.
These are parameterized with $t \in [0, 2)$:
$\begin{cases}
t \in [0, 1): x=\tan(\pi t), y = 0\\
t \in [1, 2): x=0, y = \tan(\pi(1-t))
\end{cases}$
For $t=\frac 1 2$ the point $(\pm \infty, 0)$ is the point at infinity that closes line $y=0$ in $\mathbb P^2$. And similarly for $t=\frac 3 2$ and line $x=0$.
Hence this parameterization of the two lines makes them into a closed curve, with one double point obtained for $t=0$ and $t=1$.

The right-angle turn at $(0,0)$ is because we want to connect the infinity branches that are on the same line, i.e. $(0, +\infty)$ with $(0, -\infty)$, and $(+\infty, 0)$ with $(-\infty, 0)$. For $2$ reasons:

- In $\mathbb P^2$, $(0, +\infty)$ and $(0, -\infty)$ exist and are the same point; idem for $(+\infty, 0)$ and $(-\infty, 0)$.
- This is the way hyperbolas behave.

Another option would be to connect $(+\infty, 0)$ to $(0, -\infty)$, and $(0, +\infty)$ to $(-\infty, 0)$. That would be possible if we close the plan $\mathbb R^2$ not with one point at infinity for each parallel set of lines, like in $\mathbb P^2$, but by only one point at infinity, which would topologically be a sphere $S^2$. The two lines would be a closed curve, but with two crossings, and conics do not have crossings, so this looks less natural.

Then we can take a circle $x^2+y^2=1$ centered on the origin, and parameterize it on $t \in [0,2)$ with $x = \cos (\pi t), y = \sin (\pi t)$.

This allows a bijection between the **parameterization of the two lines**, and the **parameterization of the circle**. This is *not* a bijection between the two lines and the circle, as the two lines have a double point at the origin, which correspond to two opposite points $(0, 1)$ and $(0, -1)$ on the circle.

This relation can now be made a relation between **a cone and two planes**, by adding a third dimension $z \in (-\infty, +\infty)$ which acts as a second parameter:

Two planes $y=0$ and $x=0$:
$\begin{cases}
t \in [0, 1): x=z\tan(\pi t), y = 0\\
t \in [1, 2): x=0, y = z\tan(\pi(1-t))
\end{cases}$

The cone $x^2+y^2=z^2$:
$x = z\cos(\pi t), y = z\sin(\pi t)$

However it would be more fun to have a continuous mapping between the two lines and the circle, using a third parameter, with intermediate values being ellipses and hyperbolas, so I am now working on that.

Comment: Sorry but I expected to find some insight from the answer. You have just listed the definitions of cone.

Comment: @IamThat Ah, OK. Well, the main insight is: a pair of lines in the plane is a conic, so a pair of planes in the space is a cone (in definition 2). And a pair of lines is a conic because if $L_1(x,y)=0$ and $L_2(x,y)=0$ are the equations of the two lines, $L_1(x,y)L_2(x,y)=0$ is the equation of their union, and it has degree $2$, so it is a conic.

Comment: Sorry to say Sir, but this much is fairly obvious. I expected some deeper relation between the two. Maybe something about how a line when extended to infinity in both directions can be treated as a circle or in general a closed curve (as we do in complex analysis Argand plane - stereographic projections)

Comment: Some sort of generalization on higher dimension, resulting in components of the pair of planes becoming components of the cone through a bijective transformation. I expected something along this line to hold true. My question was along those lines.

Comment: @IamThat It is well known that a line, in projective geometry, loops on itself. As for a bijection between a circular cone and two planes: it can be built with a bijection between a circle and two (crossing) lines. Take a circle, extend it to infinity on one side: that gives a parabola, then an hyperbola when the circle "returns from infinity" on the other side. Then straighten the hyperbola until its two sides meet: you get two crossing lines. But you may still say that all this is obvious, especially if building those 2D figures by cutting a cone with a plane.

Comment: @IamThat Thinking about it, what I propose above is not a bijection: the point where the two lines cross is related to two opposite points in the circle. So the intersection line of the two planes is related to two opposite lines on the cone. But still that looks like the most natural way to build a relation between two planes and a cone. To have a bijection we should express some multiplicity: the intersection of two lines, as well as the intersection of two planes, is made of (algebraically) double points.

Comment: If you could formalize this in your answer and include these explanations (of how to relate a cone to a pair of planes, building up from a pair of straight lines in 2D from a circle), I would be happy to accept the answer and award the bounty to you. 
A rigorous mathematical derivation of how cicles turn into parabolas, hyperbolas and then into pair of straight lines would be helpful as well. And if you could extend this formalization to a cone and pair of planes in 3 dimensions, the answer would be complete.

Comment: @IamThat Here is a first version. Now working on a more elaborate one with a continuous mapping between the two planes and the cone.

Comment: Sir, Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my question. Could you suggest some interesting resources to get more familiar with projective geometry? May be books, videos, online lectures?
I am a graduate in Mathematics and Computation and am familiar with linear algebra, metric spaces, basic modern algebra and introductory algegraic geometry in case it is relevant.

Comment: @IamThat Wikipedia article on projective space (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space) is good. I have also read texts in French, notably by Daniel Perrin, whose style is both clear and rigorous. He has a book in English online, although much broader than projective geometry: https://www.math.ens.psl.eu/~benoist/refs/Perrin.pdf. When counting solutions of polynomial systems, projective geometry is better behaved than standard plane geometry. There is also a beautiful duality result that exchange lines and points: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(projective_geometry)

Answer (score 0):

[image: ConicalSheet]

A definition or generalization of a *Conical Sheet* can be put into a proper perspective to be among a group of surfaces that *concurrent straight line generators* create by motion of a director line through a single concurrent point $O$ in 3-space.

The director line $ ABC..$  is an arbitrary curve. It need not be part of any bigger curve or tangential to any surface.

There is an infinite number of planes. We only view them pair wise with point of concurrency $O$. Each plane has parallel segments $(AB, ab), (BC, bc),....$ held in an *infinity of similar triangles.*

The sheet embeds into 3-space, can be flattened out as zero (Gauss) curvature surface. This is referred to as *Bending* caused by *Isometric mapping* During such isometric mapping the angle between a pair of planes changes, that is normal curvature changes. However curvature of lines such as $ AB, bc, CA,.." does not change

In particular if the origin is the concurrent point they can be typically described by a homogenous equation as special cases of conicoid

$$ ax^2+by^2+cz^2 =0 \text { or }~\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2 \pm \left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{z}{c}\right)^2  = 0 $$

If one ***Tangent plane*** you are referring to at  $(x_1, y_1, z_1 )$ should have  an equation

$$ a x x_1+ bbb_1+c zz=0$$

If a plane

$$ px+qy+rz=0 $$

touches the cone then we should have

$$\left(\frac{p^2}{a}\right) + \left(\frac{q^2}{b}\right) +\left(\frac{r^2}{c}\right)  = 0. $$

etc.